# List the names of the Employees having '%' character in their name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to display the list of employee details

```
Select * from EMPLOYEES where Name LIKE '%%%';
```

Comment: ["RTFM" and see the 'ESCAPE' option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses a `ESCAPE`:

```
where name like '%$%%' ESCAPE '$'
```

This is ANSI standard syntax.  The default escape character is `\`:

```
where name like '%\%%'
```

Or, what I would probably do in SQL Server is:

```
where name like '%[%]%'
```

SQL Server supports limited character classes but enough to escape a character.